# Exception on migrating application from jdeveloper 11.1.1.5.0 to jdeveloper 11.1.2.4.0

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have developed my project on jdeveloper 11.1.2.4.0 and then came to know that it is only for adf version and soa composite editor extension cannot be installed in jdeveloper 11.1.2.4.0.Now i have migrated my application back to jdeveloper 11.1.1.5.0 as i have to implement soa and getting severe exceptions which are as follows.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.model.adapter.bean.BeanDCDefinition
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at oracle.jbo.common.java2.JDK2ClassLoader.loadClassForName(JDK2ClassLoader.java:34)
    at oracle.jbo.common.JBOClass.forName(JBOClass.java:174)
    at oracle.adf.model.adapter.DataControlFactoryImpl.createSession(DataControlFactoryImpl.java:136)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControlReference.getDataControl(DCDataControlReference.java:167)
    at oracle.adf.model.BindingContext.instantiateDataControl(BindingContext.java:1045)
    at oracle.adf.model.dcframe.DataControlFrameImpl.doFindDataControl(DataControlFrameImpl.java:1565)
    at oracle.adf.model.dcframe.DataControlFrameImpl.internalFindDataControl(DataControlFrameImpl.java:1437)
    at oracle.adf.model.dcframe.DataControlFrameImpl.findDataControl(DataControlFrameImpl.java:1397)
    at oracle.adf.model.BindingContext.internalFindDataControl(BindingContext.java:1175)
    at oracle.adf.model.BindingContext.get(BindingContext.java:1128)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCParameter.evaluateValue(DCParameter.java:82)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCParameter.getValue(DCParameter.java:111)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.getChildByName(DCBindingContainer.java:2711)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalGet(DCBindingContainer.java:2759)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCExecutableBinding.get(DCExecutableBinding.java:115)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCUtil.findSpelObject(DCUtil.java:328)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.evaluateParameterWithElCheck(DCBindingContainer.java:1460)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.findDataControl(DCBindingContainer.java:1590)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUMethodIteratorDef$JUMethodIteratorBinding.initDataControl(JUMethodIteratorDef.java:589)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getDataControl(DCIteratorBinding.java:2416)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getSortCriteria(DCIteratorBinding.java:3771)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCInvokeMethod.setAssociatedIteratorBinding(DCInvokeMethod.java:946)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.cacheRefOnOperation(DCIteratorBinding.java:5287)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUMethodIteratorDef$JUMethodIteratorBinding.getActionBinding(JUMethodIteratorDef.java:283)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUMethodIteratorDef$JUMethodIteratorBinding.hasRefreshParametersChanged(JUMethodIteratorDef.java:527)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCExecutableBindingDef.isRefreshable(DCExecutableBindingDef.java:379)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUMethodIteratorDef.isRefreshable(JUMethodIteratorDef.java:55)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCExecutableBindingDef.isRefreshable(DCExecutableBindingDef.java:274)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3034)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:2874)
    at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.prepareModel(PageLifecycleImpl.java:115)
    at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.Lifecycle$2.execute(Lifecycle.java:137)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:197)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.access$400(ADFPhaseListener.java:23)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$PhaseInvokerImpl.startPageLifecycle(ADFPhaseListener.java:238)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$1.after(ADFPhaseListener.java:274)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFPhaseListener.java:75)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.java:53)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:399)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:186)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)

<Utils> <buildFacesMessage> ADF: Adding the following JSF error message: Object Catalog of type DataControl is not found.
oracle.jbo.NoObjException: JBO-25003: Object Catalog of type DataControl is not found.
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getDataControl(DCIteratorBinding.java:2424)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.getDataControl(DCBindingContainer.java:5058)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.initDataControl(DCIteratorBinding.java:2475)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getDataControl(DCIteratorBinding.java:2416)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.getDataControl(DCBindingContainer.java:5058)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.reportException(DCBindingContainer.java:466)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getDataControl(DCIteratorBinding.java:2438)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.getSortCriteria(DCIteratorBinding.java:3771)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCInvokeMethod.setAssociatedIteratorBinding(DCInvokeMethod.java:946)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.cacheRefOnOperation(DCIteratorBinding.java:5287)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUMethodIteratorDef$JUMethodIteratorBinding.getActionBinding(JUMethodIteratorDef.java:283)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUMethodIteratorDef$JUMethodIteratorBinding.hasRefreshParametersChanged(JUMethodIteratorDef.java:527)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCExecutableBindingDef.isRefreshable(DCExecutableBindingDef.java:379)
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUMethodIteratorDef.isRefreshable(JUMethodIteratorDef.java:55)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCExecutableBindingDef.isRefreshable(DCExecutableBindingDef.java:274)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3034)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:2874)
    at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.prepareModel(PageLifecycleImpl.java:115)
    at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.Lifecycle$2.execute(Lifecycle.java:137)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:197)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.access$400(ADFPhaseListener.java:23)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$PhaseInvokerImpl.startPageLifecycle(ADFPhaseListener.java:238)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$1.after(ADFPhaseListener.java:274)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFPhaseListener.java:75)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.java:53)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:399)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:186)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Regards,
Furqan Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

You can't migrate backward an ADF project - 11.1.2.4 uses libraries that are not there in 11.1.1.*.